# Django: Make a query inside a class

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to make a query inside a class of my model. I have the following model where a contract is made when a person has a project.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    is_doctor  = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Phd?")

class Project(models.Model):
    name                 = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    principal_researcher = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank = True, verbose_name=_(u"Researcher associated with the project"))

 class Contract(models.Model):
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    project       = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
    type_contract = models.CharField(max_length = 9, blank = True, verbose_name = _(u"Type of contract(Full time/grant/Partial time...)"))
    starting_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    ending_date   = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    term          = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True)
```

I want to create a class where the user will be able to make this query:

*Tell me all the people, without Phd,  with full time contract with a contract among two dates.*

So the user only has to enter two dates to get the query.

(All of this from the Admin interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "inside a class".

You can make your query like this:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    is_doctor=False,
    contract__type_contract='full',
    contract__starting_date__gte=start_date,
    contract__ending_date__lte=end_date
)
```

If you want to define a method to execute this query, that is normally done inside a model manager:

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def full_time_no_doctors_contract_between(self, start_date, end_date):
        return self.filter(...)


class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PersonManager()
```

and now you can do:

```
Person.objects.full_time_no_doctors_contract_between(start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Daniel What I meant by "inside a class" was that I want the user go to a class in the Admin interface, enter two dates and the  result is shown, separate from the Person class. So I don't know how to do it. Where would I put?: Person.objects.full_time_no_doctors_contract_between(start_date, end_date)